# When exactly is AppWidgetProvider.onRestored() being called?

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

In which cases should i override onRestored?

Are they just referring to the backup which can be enabled/disabled in the manifest? Is it possible that this method get's called when the app get's updated too? Or under any other circumstances where the appWidgetIds might change? I think the ids are supposed to stay the same forever but not all manufacturers/launchers treat widgets the same way...

Could this be useful against phantom/ghost widgets?

```
/**
 * Called in response to the {@link AppWidgetManager#ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED} broadcast
 * when instances of this AppWidget provider have been restored from backup.  If your
 * provider maintains any persistent data about its widget instances, override this method
 * to remap the old AppWidgetIds to the new values and update any other app state that may
 * be relevant.
 *
 * <p>This callback will be followed immediately by a call to {@link #onUpdate} so your
 * provider can immediately generate new RemoteViews suitable for its newly-restored set
 * of instances.
 *
 * {@more}
 *
 * @param context
 * @param oldWidgetIds
 * @param newWidgetIds
 */
public void onRestored(Context context, int[] oldWidgetIds, int[] newWidgetIds) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onRestored()` method is closely related to Android's backup/restore process.

In Android, it is possible to backup/restore app data to Google Drive through `BackupManagerService`. At this time, when the backed up data is restored, the app widget data is also restored, and `onRestored()` is called when the restoration is complete.

In addition, `AppWidgetId` is managed by `uid`, and it is seen in the form of increasing from 0. Since the id can be changed at the time of restoration, `oldId` and `newId` are delivered when `onRestored()` is called.

The process for this can be traced in `AppWidgetServiceImpl.java`, and for an overview of the Android backup system, refer to the url below.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup